# SQL keep only the last X rows

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table in which the id is constantly increasing. The `Id` does not always increase by the same value and it is not an `auto_increment` due to a api, but it increases permanently. Example:

| Id | other content |
| --- | --- |
| 501 | xxx |
| 500 | yyy |
| 365 | qqq |
| ... | ... |

Now I just want to keep the last X rows, remove rows with lower ids. I was able to find a similar but not a working solution for myself to this problem.

I thought that something like that would work, but there is an error:

```sql
DELETE FROM `games` WHERE `matchId` NOT IN(SELECT `matchId` FROM `games` ORDER BY `matchId` DESC LIMIT X)
```

> #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT &
> IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Im running the mysql version 8.0.27 on a phpmyadmin 5.1.1 web interface.

**Is there a way to keep the newest x rows without triggering this error?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS (
 SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id DESC) AS rownum FROM games
)
DELETE games FROM games JOIN cte USING (id) WHERE rownum > 2;
```

Comment: Note to readers who might try this with MariaDB: MariaDB currently only supports common table expressions followed by SELECT, not DELETE. This is one of many incompatibilities between MariaDB and MySQL.

Comment: Thanks, works for me! Although mysql says WITH is an unknown statement, all except 2 entries have been deleted.

Comment: I believe that error comes from the phpmyadmin parser, not MySQL. Reportedly fixed in phpadmin's mysql parser version 5.5.0, according to this issue: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/sql-parser/issues/165

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE instead:

```
with u as
(select Id from table_name order by Id desc limit 5)
delete from table_name
where Id not in(select Id from u)
```